# Using chrome.runtime.sendMessage does not yield a response in Firefox Web Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm trying to write a cross browser extension that is using a background script and a popup that cross-communicate:

In the background script:

```
class Listener{
    listen(cb){
        chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((transmission, sender, messageResponseFn) => {
            cb(transmission, messageResponseFn);
            return true;
        });
    }
}

export default new Listener();
```

In the popup:

```
class Emitter{
    send(message, payload){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ message, payload }, (responseMessage) => {
                resolve(responseMessage);
            });
        });
    }
}

export default new Emitter();
```

This works as expected in Chrome, yet in Firefox the sent response (the function is called correctly and does not throw) will never arrive in my `Emitter`. Am I using this API wrong? Are there any differences between Firefox and Chrome that I am not aware of? From what I read in [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Chrome_incompatibilities) the `runtime.sendMessage` API should be fully supported.

FWIW, here's an example repository demonstrating the issue: https://github.com/m90/firefox-webextension-issue

Comment: Probably related [bugfix](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1202481) (FF44). Also try asking on [Mozilla addon dev forum](https://discourse.mozilla-community.org/c/add-ons/development).

Comment: Ok, thanks, will try asking on the forum, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [confirmed bug in the WebExtension API](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1228044) so there's not much to do about it.

Comment: Probably worth updating that the bug is now RESOLVED FIXED.

Comment: is this really resolved? @Xan I am still not able to receive a message in firefox, even thought this works perfectly in chrome and edge.

Comment: It still doesn't work. If I switch `chrome` to `browser`, then it works in Firefox.